# Making an Access Database With Multiple Values for Certain Fields

Tags: database, ms-access

For a small project I was looking at doing I was considering making a database in Microsoft Access 2016 that would store characters from a TV show, to allow an easy way to search a character and see all episodes they may have been on, or what episode had the most blondes, etc.

The issue I'm running into is figuring out how to setup my tables to record episodes with people, and I've seen many people say that multivalue fields are a poor idea in most scenarios.

I was looking at some simple tables that may resemble:

CHARACTER: CharacterName(PK), HairColour, Gender

EPISODE: EpisodeNumber(PK), EpisodeDate, CharacterName(FK)

The issue here is obviously most characters appear in multiple episodes, and all episodes would have more than a single character. What would be a good way of resolving this many-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the character name as a Primary Key - I can't think of any at the moment, but there's bound to be shows that have different characters who share the same name.  Off the top of my head.... you could have Captain Kirk in Star Trek and (possibly) a Captain Kirk in Flying Doctors.

As for resolving the many to many relationship you'll need a third table to hold it.  The table will have two Foreign Keys referencing the Primary Keys in Character and Episode and both fields will make up the tables composite Primary Key.

So:

```
CharacterName | Episode  
     1        |    1  
     1        |    2  
     2        |    1
     2        |    2
```

You can then pull details from each table based on this:

```
SELECT  Character.CharacterName, Episode.EpisodeNumber
FROM    (Character INNER JOIN Joining_Tbl ON Character.CharacterName = Joining_Tbl.CharacterName)
                   INNER JOIN Episode ON Joining_Tbl.EpisodeNumber = Episode.EpisodeNumber
WHERE   Character.HairColour = 'Blonde'
```

**Note** - the Episode table doesn't contain the character details.  It only contains information that is unique to that episode - the episode number, date, name.  You could add the series number to this table - it's not unique to the episode, but it won't change and can be used as a Foreign Key linking to a table containing series information.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary key for all tables should be auto number fields.
You should avoid multi value fields.

Part of the answer is determined by the user interface experience you are going to build.  The Character table in the end is a pick list.

The Episode table should be the basis/record source for the Main form.  Then you need another table: EpisodeCharacter.  This new table is the basis for a sub form in the Main form and it is set up to call in a record from the Character table.

One must build the Character table.  Then in episode, one selects the episode or creates a record and the EpisodeCharacter is the many table to it.

www.CahabaData.com